# button.Enabled = state что это значит?

Tags: c#

Объясните пожалуйста, что это за такое свойство у поля?

```cs
    void ButtonState(bool state)
    {
        button_ClearPT.Enabled = state;
        button_Encrypt.Enabled = state;
        button_Decrypt.Enabled = state;
    }
```

Спрашивал у гугла, но он молчит или я не там ищу
Свойство [control.enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx) судя по msdn-у, может принимать два значения только правда или лож, но что такое **state**?

Comment: Это значит, что кнопки будут активны или не активны в зависимости от значения входного параметра state который передается в метод.

Comment: state - это параметр вашего метода, имеющий тип `bool` и принимающий эти самые два значения

Comment: state - это идентификатор, который идентифицирует имя параметра. Имя может быть любым удолетворяющим условия имени хоть `a` хоть `E6` хоть `iamnotunder_stand`

Comment: @Atlantis спасибо, вроде бы понятно стало

Comment: @nick_n_a это понятно, но от куда оно берет его не понимаю, документации по этому не нашел.

Comment: Имя вы задаёте сами. То что вы хотите узнать скорее всего называется cross reference (xref, xrefs). В VS2015  эта функция встроена, а если иначе - второй вариант поставить точку останова и смотреть "стек вызовов"  - тогда будет понятно какая функция вызвала вашу. Но тогда вопрос нужно переформулировать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`state` - это переменная с типом `bool` которая является параметром вашей функции, она соответственно может быть названа произвольно.

А `bool` - принимает значения только значения `True`/`False`

Значение параметр получает при вызове этой функции. Можете посмотреть где используется эта функция кликнув на ней в коде правой клавишей и выбрав пункт `Find Usages`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо за подсказку, вообще она используется только в двух кнопках, перед блоком **try** стоит `ButtonState(false)` и после **catch** блока стоит `ButtonState(true)`, у меня больше возникает вопрос, как оно работает, как я понимаю, пока не выполнилось то что в блоке **try** кнопка неактивна? так?

Comment: @PavelFedorov когда вызывается функция с значением true преданным в параметр - кнопки становятся активны. А когда с false - кнопки деактивируются.

Comment: значит я правильно думал, @V. Dmitriy спасибо за разъяснение.